# Scrolling website where background remains stationary and content transitions on click or scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions, transition

Im looking for a template or a place that teaches how to create a website like these for example:

http://www.refletcommunication.com/en
https://www.artistsweb.com/work

Where the page basically stays the same but you can kinda scroll through and the content changes. Or click links and the content changes. but background stay neutral.

I hope this is a valid question. I've designed a portfolio site for myself which would have this effect just not sure what its called so i can learn how to code it. It would have content on the main page with links on the right hand side. and if you scroll or click a link the content will transition to the new content. while the background remains stationary.

hope that makes sense! Thanks

Comment: please provide an MCV example of what you have tried.  for more info, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It's not really a valid question, but I have a similar interest, and so far I found DevTips channel's parallax tutorials: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=STwoa-9jxi0&list=PLqGj3iMvMa4IyCbhul-PdeiDqmh4ooJzk some helpful libraries: greensock and scrollmagic (Youtube ihatetomatoes), and a bit of guidance to use requestanimationframe instead of onscrool as per https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O39OEPC20GM <- plus other optimization techniques. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly then the one way which I use is to stack divs with `position: absolute` at top of each other and then just switch the **active** class which will indicate which element is currently visible and this class will have `z-index: 100` or 1000 or any number which you want but it has to be higher than number of stacked elements. In HTML you will add the class **active** to the element which will be visible after loading the page. Then with JS you will change the element which has the class **active**. In JS I use:

jQuery: https://jquery.com/download/
jQuery Mouse Wheel Plugin: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="vertically-stacked active"> //first visible bannner
        <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="vertically-stacked">  //visible only if class active is added
        <h1>World</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

You may have infinite number of vertically-stacked elements.

**CSS:**

```
.container    //container of vertically stacked elements
{
    position: relative    //or absolute but not static 
}

.vertically-stacked
{
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    transition: all .25s;   //time which takes to switch the active element
    -moz-transition: all .25s;
    -o-transition: all .25s;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s;
}

.vertically-stacked.active
{
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).on('mousewheel', function (e)
{
    var $verticallyStacked = $('.vertically-stacked'),
        oldActive = $verticallyStacked.index($('.vertically-stacked.active')),
        newActive;

    $verticallyStacked.eq(oldActive).removeClass('active');
    if (e.deltaY < 0) //scroll down
    {       
        newActive = oldActive + 1;
    }
    else //scroll up
    {
        newActive = oldActive - 1;
    }
    $verticallyStacked.eq(newActive).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: How would each div be set up? Similar to this? Ive only worked with active classes once before pretty long ago. https://jsfiddle.net/ebmanfcL/

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear so I edited the answer to be 100% clear. In description I changed referring to class active as class .active, in JS I changed class to vertically-stacked and corrected semicolon in line: var $verticallyStacked = $('.vertically-stacked'), to comma. Here is edited JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ebmanfcL/1/  

PS: jQuery Mouse Wheel Plugin doesn't have to be directly in main.js file as in JSFiddle, I added it there because it was the only way how to include the plugin in JSFiddle.

Comment: Thank you that does make more sense. Im trying to add this to my code but when i copy the script over it doesnt work. I tried Putting in in <script></script> and its own js file. If i put it in a <script></script> does it need to be in the html or body?

Comment: This is how i tried to add it to my code. I think if i can get it working on my pc. Then i would figure it out hopefully. https://jsfiddle.net/2xt7vyxf/

Comment: `<script>` needs to be in `<head>`, it's better to make separate JS file and then put `<script src="filename.js"></script>` into `<head>`, e.g. `<script src="main.js"></script>` then you have to include jQuery and jQuery Mouse Wheel Plugin into `<head>`, try to find external links to these frameworks or download it into your PC and link it as main.js file, e.g. if you have external link it may look like `<script src="http://stackoverflow.com/jquery.js></script>` (This is not an actual link, it is just an example). Every framework like jQuery which is not in native JS needs to be included.